# xslt: css not wotking in html page

Tags: html, css, spring-mvc, xslt

In spring project i am using XsltViewResolver to convert xml into html `org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xslt.XsltViewResolver` for

In html output code css is not working.
XML string:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<kblc:kblcImportLc xmlns:kblc='http://www.kblc.com/schema/v1/kblc'>
    <kblc:ImportStructureLC>
        <kblc:ImportLCHeader>
            <kblc:ApplicantInfo>
                <kblc:ApplicantName>ApplicantTest</kblc:ApplicantName>
                <kblc:ApplicantAddress>Spring Villa Park</kblc:ApplicantAddress>
                <kblc:ApplicantCity>London</kblc:ApplicantCity>
                <kblc:ApplicantPostalCode>HA8 7EB</kblc:ApplicantPostalCode>
                <kblc:ApplicantCountry>UK</kblc:ApplicantCountry>
                <kblc:ApplicantRegion>consistent</kblc:ApplicantRegion>
                <kblc:ApplicantContactName>AA</kblc:ApplicantContactName>
                <kblc:ApplicantEmail>email@mail.com</kblc:ApplicantEmail>
                <kblc:ApplicantPhone>5856965456</kblc:ApplicantPhone>
                <kblc:ApplicantFax>021548795</kblc:ApplicantFax>
            </kblc:ApplicantInfo>
        </kblc:ImportLCHeader>
    </kblc:ImportStructureLC>
</kblc:kblcImportLc>
```

XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:kblc="http://www.kblc.com/schema/v1/kblc">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>Sports Info</title>
                <style>
                    .HelpTitle {
                    font: 13px verdana, sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    margin-right: 5px;
                    }
                    .HelpText {
                    font: 11px verdana, sans-serif;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    margin-right: 5px;
                    }
                    .HelpHighlight {
                    background-color: #55be28 ;
                    }
                </style>
                <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function init () {
                    var url = new URL(document.location);
                    var str2 = url.searchParams.get("tagName");

                    document.getElementById(str2).className = "HelpHighlight";
                    document.getElementById("ErrorString").value="someContent";
                    document.getElementById("ErrorString123").value=str2;
                    document.getElementById(str2).focus();
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body onload="init();">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="kblc:kblcImportLc/kblc:ImportStructureLC">
        <!-- Start ApplicantName -->
        <div id="ApplicantName">
            <br/>
            <div class="HelpTitle">ApplicantName</div>
            <br/>
            <div class="HelpText">
                <xsl:value-of select="kblc:ImportLCHeader/kblc:ApplicantInfo/kblc:ApplicantName" />
            </div>
            <div id="ErrorString123"></div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <!-- End ApplicantName -->


        <!-- Start ApplicantAddress -->
        <div id="ApplicantAddress">
            <br/>
            <div class="HelpTitle">ApplicantAddress</div>
            <br/>
            <div class="HelpText">
                <xsl:value-of select="kblc:ImportLCHeader/kblc:ApplicantInfo/kblc:ApplicantAddress" />
            </div>
            <div id="ErrorString"></div>
            <br/>
        </div>
        <!-- End ApplicantAddress -->

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

HTML output:

```
<html xmlns:kblc="http://www.kblc.com/schema/v1/kblc">
  <head>
    <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Sports Info</title>
    <style>
                    .HelpTitle {
                    font: 13px verdana, sans-serif;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    text-decoration: underline;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    margin-right: 5px;
                    }
                    .HelpText {
                    font: 11px verdana, sans-serif;
                    margin-left: 5px;
                    margin-right: 5px;
                    }
                    .HelpHighlight {
                    background-color: #55be28 ;
                    }
                </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
                    function init () {
                    var url = new URL(document.location);
                    var str2 = url.searchParams.get("tagName");

                    document.getElementById(str2).className = "HelpHighlight";
                    document.getElementById("ErrorString").value="someContent";
                    document.getElementById("ErrorString123").value=str2;
                    document.getElementById(str2).focus();
                    }
                </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init();">

    <div id="ApplicantName">
      <br>
      <div class="HelpTitle">ApplicantName</div>
      <br>
      <div class="HelpText">ApplicantTest</div>
      <div id="ErrorString123"></div>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div id="ApplicantAddress">
      <br>
      <div class="HelpTitle">ApplicantAddress</div>
      <br>
      <div class="HelpText">Spring Villa Park</div>
      <div id="ErrorString"></div>
      <br>
    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

In this html css is not working.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work? If I paste your resulting HTML in a .html file, then it works as expected for me locally.

Comment: What are you trying to do in the JavaScript? Giving a `value` to a `<div>` won't do anything. Are you sure you have the correct `tagName` parameter? (This is case sensitive.) And what browser are you using? `url.searchParams` is not implemented in IE11.

Comment: @MrLister yes when we open this html code manualy by save as .html file css is working ... but then its open by java code (Spring mvc) css is not working ...

Comment: @MrLister html tag have name space is this cause the css is not working? `<html xmlns:kblc="http://www.kblc.com/schema/v1/kblc">`

Answer (score 1):

**From comments**

> html tag have name space is this cause the css is not working?

That shouldn't be the case. But if you want to not output that strange namespace declaration in an HTML document, then use the [`exclude-result-prefixes` atribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#literal-result-element) in the `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:kblc="http://www.kblc.com/schema/v1/kblc"
                exclude-result-prefixes="kblc">
```